# Linear Algebra - Determine Value of a for no solution linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The question is to find the value(s) of "$a$" in the linear system so that it has no solution.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&a\\1&1&a&1\\3&4&a^2-2&1\end{bmatrix}$$

And so I tried to get the $\operatorname{rref}(A)$ which I got to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2a-1&2-a\\0&1&1-a&a-1\\0&0&a^2-2a-3&-a-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I am pretty much stuck here and I am learning lin alg on my own so what would be the best way in approaching for a solution here?

I was also going to try factoring $A_{33}$ to see what values of "$a$” might work which I also got $a = 3$ or $-1$ but didn't know how to interpret these answers.

Comment: like $\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\1&1&a&1\\3&4&a^2-2&1\end{array}\right]$?
The right column is a vector?

Comment: Welcome. Use MathJax for formatting mathematical text in future; I’ve edited this in for you this time

Comment: If you rref is correct, the either of the roots $-3$ or $1$ of $A_{33}$ will make the bottom row zero, and $-a-1$ non-zero, so the system will have no solutions

Comment: Okay so from a = 3 and -1 I see that if I input it the only solution would be 3. Thank you! I thought that I would have to fully row reduce for the answer.

Comment: My comment was wrong; as @JoseCarlosSantos says, there are infinitely many solutions at $a=-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\1&1&a&1\\3&4&a^2-2&1\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow[R_3\to R_3-3R_1]{R_2\to R_2-R_1}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\0&-1&a-1&1-a\\0&-2&a^2-5&1-3a\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow[]{R_3\to R_3-2R_2}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\0&-1&a-1&1-a\\0&0&a^2-2a-3&-1-a\end{array}\right]$$
if $a=-1$ then the last row turns into a zero row:
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$
which is clearly solvable.
else:
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\0&-1&a-1&1-a\\0&0&a^2-2a-3&-1-a\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow[]{R_3\to\frac{1}{a+1}R_3}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&2&1&a\\0&-1&a-1&1-a\\0&0&a-3&-1\end{array}\right]$$
If $a=3$ than the last row is a contradiction, so no solution.
else, the determinant is non-zero and thus a solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

If $a^2-2a-3\ne0$, then the system has one and only one solution.

Otherwise, $a=3$ or $a=-1$. If $a=-1$, the bottom line consists only of zeros, and therefore the system has infinitely many solutions. Finally, if $a=3$, the bottom line corresponds to the equation $0=-4$, and then the system has no solutions.